# Android Eclipse compatible targets problem

Tags: android, eclipse, compatibility, device

I have a Sony Ericsson Xperia Mini device which I use to test android app development. Earlier it is working fine if I run any project from Eclipse as Android App. I can select the device and run the program in that device. But after formatting I reinstall all the systems(e.g. eclipse, ADT plug in, driver of the device), but when I try to run the program, it is telling 'No compatible targets found', although I have connected the device properly. Actually the eclipse-ADT plug in system not all getting the device. What may cause this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is due to setting in the device...non-market app and USB debugging should be allowed.

Answer (score 0):

Try to re-install your mobile's drivers..

Comment: tried that also...but not working...actually the device and PC companion is working fine without development work.